# If statement matching words separated by special char

Tags: bash, unix

I'm new to unix. I have a file with an unknown amount of lines in format: "password, username" and I'm trying to make a function that checks this file against user inputted login.

What I have so far:

Accounts file format:
AAA###, firstname.lastname

```
echo "Please enter Username:"
read username
if cut -d "," -f2 accounts | grep -w -q $username
    then
    echo "Success"
fi
```

This function will return Success for inputs "firstname" "lastname" and "firstname.lastname" when I only want it to return for "firstname.lastname"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can usernames contain special characters, besides dots?

Comment: @wjandrea only dots for the usernames. They can also have uppercase letters

Answer (score 2):

You could go for an exact match, with `^` and `$` anchors, like this:

```
echo "Please enter Username:"
read username
if cut -d "," -f2 accounts | grep -q "^$username$"; then
    echo "Success"
fi
```

While this would work even when the user gives an empty input, you might want to explicitly check for that.

Comment: Quoting wouldn't have caused this issue. The issue is because `-w` won't stop `firstname` or `lastname` from matching with `firstname.lastname`.

Comment: Thanks but now it doesn't match on anything, including firstname.lastname

Comment: @codeforester, I misread his use case. I saw "firstname lastname" due to the lack of comma

Comment: Do you have leading or trailing whitespaces in your file, by chance?  Please post a sample of your file.

Comment: Actually I managed to figure it out with the help of @glenn jackman. The separator is "comma space" so I used `"^ $username$"` and it worked!

Comment: @Kuro, more reliable to make it `^ *` or `^ ?`; if you leave the space in as a literal, the command wouldn't work without it.

Comment: @Kuro, ...the other thing to be wary of is whether your usernames can contain glob characters. If the user says their name is `.*`, then `grep` will claim that **any** name matches, even if no such account really exists. Because this answer has `grep` treat user-provided data as a regex in a security-sensitive context, I have trouble recommending it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fair enough. this is more of a school assignment but I'll keep the question open to see if there are better options.

Answer (score 2):

If you loop over the file within the shell, you can use string equality operators instead of regular expressions:

```
read -rp "enter Username (first.last): " username
shopt -s extglob
found=false
while IFS=, read -r pass uname _othertext; do
    # from your question, it looks like the separator is "comma space"
    # so we'll remove leading whitespace from the $uname
    if [[ "$username" = "${uname##+([[:blank:]])}" ]]; then
        echo "Success"
        found=true
        break
    fi
done < accounts
if ! $found; then
    echo "$username not found in accounts file"
fi
```

`while read` loops in the shell are very slow compared to `grep`, but depending on the size of the accounts file you may not notice.

Comment: `while IFS=, read -r pass uname _; do` -- without some placeholder, all remaining fields will be appended to `uname`.

Comment: Might also want an explicit `shopt -s extglob`; IIRC, whether extglobs are *implicitly* enabled on the RHS of `[[ ]]` varies by release.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956087/if-statement-matching-words-separated-by-special-char/51956678#comment90863685_51956248), the issue is that the field separator is a comma then a space, not just a comma. `cut` can't do multi-character delimiters, but `awk` can. In your code, replace

```
cut -d "," -f2
```

with

```
awk -F ", " '{print $2}'
```

---

By the way, there are a few things needed to guard against user input:

```
# Use "-r" to avoid backslash escapes.
read -rp "Please enter Username:" username
# Always quote variables ("$username").
# Use "grep -F" for fixed-string mode.
# Use "--" to prevent arguments being interpreted as options.
if awk -F ", " '{print $2}' accounts | grep -wqF -- "$username"; then
    echo "Success"
fi
```

Comment: The `read` command suggested by glenn's answer also supports multiple delimiters -- `while IFS=', ' read -r pass uname _; do` will do just that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I specifically mean *a multi-character* delimiter (comma followed by space), not multiple delimiters (comma and/or space). Though I'm not sure how important the distinction is.

Comment: awk can do what grep does, so you could write `awk -v x="$username" '$1 == x {exit 1}' file && echo not found || echo found`